# Trying to open object browser dialog using Office js Addin

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, office-js-helpers

I'm developing a Word Add-in (Word API + Office.js) and I'm wondering if it's possible to open word embedded object browser dialog

Currently my word template has few content controls with data, now i am trying to open object browser dialog to attach office object(excel) to the document as shown in the image when the user clicks on button.

[image]

so want check whether Word API has a way to open word object browser dialog? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the (current version of the) Office JS APIs has no access to Word's built-in dialog boxes. You'd need to create your own interface. For the dialog box you show, considering you want only Excel workbooks(?) that should be relatively easy. The more difficult part would be actually inserting the object - that would (currently) have to be done using OOXML.